# Why CloudFront-Viewer-City is always null?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have created a CloudFront distribution just for testing purposes.

Why is `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` passed to the origin but `CloudFront-Viewer-City` is not?

**Settings**

I believe these are the two relevant settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show CloudFront-Viewer-* other than CloudFront-Viewer-Country, please create a custom Origin Request Policy. In the policy, you must select "All viewer headers and whitelisted CloudFront-* headers" and specify what headers in CloudFront-Viewer-* to pass to origin.

[image]